# How to calculate cosine similarity between two columns? - Python

Tags: python, cosine-similarity

```
tfvect = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True, stop_words = 'english')
wholeword = df_all['search_term']+" "+df_all['product_title']
vocab = tfvect.fit_transform(wholeword)
st = tfvect.transform(df_all['search_term'])
pt = tfvect.transform(df_all['product_title'])
```

I want to get the cosine similarity between each row of st and pt and store it in df_all['similarity'].

Answer (score 0):

use scipy.distance.cosine(v1,v2) for each pair of rows
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html